# Decimal values in QProgressBar

Tags: qt

I have a `QProgressBar` to display a realtime reading of a sensor. The sensor can take values from `0` to `2`. How do I enable the `QProgressBar` to display all the decimal values from `0 - 2`.

I tried this:

```
 ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 2);
```

but this just show integer values (display when the value crosses 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the sensor gives you decimal values.
Since the `QProgressBar` uses integer values you will have to scale the values you receive from the sensor.

For example using a factor of 100:

```
ui->progressBar->setRange(0, <maxSensorValue> * 100);

ui->progressBar->setValue(  <receivedSensorValue> * 100 );
```